# Pointer to rvalue reference illegal?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int a1 = 1;
    int a2 = 2;

    int&& r = a1 + a2; // rvalue reference
    r++;
    std::cout << r << std::endl;

    int* p = &r; // what is this if not pointer to reference?
    std::cout << &r << " " << p << " " << *p << std::endl;

    *p++;
    std::cout << &r << " " << p << " " << *p << std::endl;

}
```

cppreference.com [claims](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference):

> Because references are not objects, there are no arrays of references,
> no pointers to references, and no references to references

However what is `int* p = &r` if not a *pointer to reference*?

Comment: `p` points to what `r` refers to, not to `r` which isn't an object.

Comment: There's a temporary object of type `int` that `r` is bound to. It is this object whose value is incremented with `r++`, and this object that `p` points to. The lifetime of that temporary is extended to that of the reference.

Comment: `int *` is not a pointer to a reference, it's a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: `&r` is the *address of the object that `r` references*.  And `int* p` is *pointer to an int*.  There is no "pointer to reference" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However what is int* p = &r if not a pointer to reference?

It's a pointer to `int`. That is, `int *`. It points to whatever the reference points to, not to the reference itself.

A pointer to reference would be `int &*` - and this doesn't compile.

---

You can also test it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void PrintType()
{
    std::cout <<
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    __FUNCSIG__
    #else
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    #endif
    << '\n';
}
```

Then `PrintType<decltype(&r)>()` prints something like `void PrintType() [T = int *]`. Note, no `&`.

Comment: Had to fumble a bit with `PrintType` function (I compile with g++ 11.3 on Ubuntu 22.04), got `void PrintType(T) [with T = int*]`

Comment: @vtm11 It works as is [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5TqsKGnnv).

Comment: Yes, just missed closing brackets () in `PrintType<decltype(&r)>`

Comment: @vtm11 Ah, that. Edited.

Comment: Pretty strange, gcc just silently skips `PrintType<decltype(&r)>` call without closing brackets (), no compile time warnings or errors

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand and mixed 2 separate concepts here - one is the type of an object and another is the value of that object. In this line:

```
int *p = &r;
```

you define `p` to have **type** `pointer to int` and there is no way in C++ to declare/define a **type** `pointer to reference to int` which what cppreference.com means.

Value it holds is an address of object in memory to which reference `r` refers, but it is irrelevant though to that statement.